# how to post serialized data in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

i want to take a `List<Product>` and POST it as serialized data to another page (really just .ashx page), is this possible in asp.net web forms?

**Update** I know I can use session to pass the generic list to my handler but would it be better post as serialized data? Pros and Cons please? Is one better than the other for heavy loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer that serializes to and from json format.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: Is it better to post serialized data then to use session? if so, why?

Comment: you use serialization to move data between systems/layers EX: moving data from server to silverlight app on client, or moving data from ajax app on client to server, or expose data to a service for external systems. Session is used only on server to get and set data in memory so session will be accessed only on server

Comment: is performance an issue under heavy load between the two? forgive me, i maybe comparing apples and oranges

Comment: yes sure, session is a user specific space in server memory this means if you are storing data in session to a 100 users visiting your site in the same time you will need to allocate enough memory for your 100 chunk of data. You don't need this in the other case because you are just passing data from server to client and not storing anything. however the headache here will be in the serialization process itself which depends on the complexity of your objects